# How to use a BAPA Z3 theory plugin?

Tags: z3

I'm trying to run this [Boolean Algebra with Presburger Arithmetic Plug-In](https://github.com/psuter/bapa-z3) for the Z3 solver. I installed Z3 and [ScalaZ3](https://github.com/epfl-lara/ScalaZ3) and `sbt test` runs fine.

However, I have no idea how to put it all together.

All I could find in the (old) Z3 documentation was the examples section, which does not help at all.

I know the plug-in interface is deprecated, but I just want to run that plug-in (using an old Z3 version is OK).

How do I get Z3 to use the plug-in through the ScalaZ3 interface and how do I input the constraints in? (examples are given in bapaZ3/bapa-z3-master/src/main/scala/bapa/)

When I try

```
java -jar scalaz3_2.10-2.1.jar
```

I just get

```
no main manifest attribute, in scalaz3_2.10-2.1.jar
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is likely that you need to use an older version of ScalaZ3, as theory plugin support has been pulled out after Z3 did. I will try to get a running demo for you.